# Rails Stripe: How do I cancel subscription?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using devise and in devise/edit I had put a "cancel my subscription" button but I'm not 100% how to get it to work.

How do I allow users to unsubscribe from stripe? Here is the error I got, any help is appreciated

[image]

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= button_to "Cancel my Subscription", canceled_path, :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
```

**Migration to User Model**

```
class AddExtraDetailsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
      add_column :users, :subscribed, :boolean, :default => false
      add_column :users, :stripeid, :string
  end
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    resources :subscribe

    get '/cancel_plan' => 'subscribes#cancel_plan'

    devise_for :users do
        resources :posts 
        resources :products
    end

    get 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user

end
```

**SubscribesController.rb**

```
class SubscribesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!


    def new
    end

    def update
        token = params[:stripeToken]
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            :card => token,
            :plan => 2,
            :email => current_user.email               
        )

        current_user.subscribed = true
        current_user.stripeid = customer.id
        current_user.save

        redirect_to user_path, :notice => "Your subscription was setup!"
    end

def cancel_plan
    @user = current_user
    if @user.cancel_user_plan(params[:customer_id])
      @user.update_attributes(customer_id: nil, plan_id: 1)
      flash[:notice] = "Canceled subscription."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error canceling your subscription. Please notify us."
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button has the `:method => :delete` while your routes defines a `get` for `/cancel_plan`. Change

```
get '/cancel_plan' => 'subscribes#cancel_plan'
```

to

```
delete '/cancel_plan' => 'subscribes#cancel_plan'
```

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting `undefined method cancel_plan for #<User:0x007fa7f6db9200>` ? What can I do about that?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got `canceled_path` from in your button. I think it should be `cancel_plan_path`.

Comment: sorry I updated it after your answer. I should change the questions to make it accurate. Though with it being `cancel_plan_path`, I am still getting the undefined method error

Comment: where exactly are you getting the error? Can you point out which line is getting the error? is it `@user.cancel_user_plan(params[:customer_id])`, I can't tell exactly cus I don't see where you implemented `cancel_user_plan`

Comment: maybe it's because `params[:customer_id]` is nil, because I don't see where that value is coming from. It should probably be `if @user.cancel_user_plan(current_user.stripid])` if you are storing the customer token inside stripeid for the user.